# How to convert from a ESSCertId certHash to a x509SKI?

Tags: cryptography

In a RFC 3161 Timestamp Token, How can I convert the certHash of the ESSCertID into a x509SKI?

For example, in [this timestamp token](https://lapo.it/asn1js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the certHash is hex-encoded as

```
5A25B4B5D82C19118C496917A4EA53309A859DDB
```

which converted to base-64 is

```
WiW0tdgsGRGMSWkXpOpTMJqFnds=
```

but I know from the [EU Trusted List](https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/tl-browser/#/tl/DE/5/12) that the x509SKI should be

```
t0SsyqkWH9a3+KEASdguv/5fY8g=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ESSCertID structure contains the SHA-1 hash of the whole certificate.

The Subject Key Identifier is any of:

1. The SHA-1 hash of the public key, as the content bytes of the SubjectPublicKeyInfo encoding.
2. ski = option_1[13..20]; ski[0] = 0x40 | (ski[0] & 0x0F)
3. The SHA-1 hash of the public key, as the fully encoded SubjectPublicKeyInfo
4. Anything else that the CA decides.

So there's not really a calculatable step to get from one to the other.  Especially because of (4).

Certificate Transparency logs do help, though, since you can search them for certificates by many criteria.  https://crt.sh/?q=5A25B4B5D82C19118C496917A4EA53309A859DDB (searching for the SHA-1 value from the ESSCertID) found the certificate, and its Subject Key Identifier is `B7:44:AC:CA:A9:16:1F:D6:B7:F8:A1:00:49:D8:2E:BF:FE:5F:63:C8`, which is the hex version of your base64 string.